# SQL group by and date intervals

Tags: sql

I've got two tables like this:

```
                  TABLE1 (SENDS)
 ------------------------------------------------
| ReceiptId | JobId |  SK  |       LogDate       |
|-----------|-------|------|---------------------|
| 0000001   | 67789 | 4151 | 6/4/2018 2:31:44 AM |
|-----------|-------|------|---------------------|
| 0000002   | 67789 | 4151 | 6/4/2018 8:25:50 AM |
|-----------|-------|------|---------------------|
| 0000003   | 67789 | 4151 | 6/4/2018 7:42:09 PM |
 ------------------------------------------------


           TABLE2 (CLICKS)
 ------------------------------------
| JobId |  SK  |       LogDate       |
|-------|------|---------------------|
| 67789 | 4151 | 6/4/2018 4:51:23 AM |
|-------|------|---------------------|
| 67789 | 4151 | 6/4/2018 5:32:52 AM |
|-------|------|---------------------|
| 67789 | 4151 | 6/4/2018 7:12:03 AM |
|-------|------|---------------------|
| 67789 | 4151 | 6/4/2018 5:14:37 PM |
|-------|------|---------------------|
| 67789 | 4151 | 6/4/2018 6:07:12 PM |
|-------|------|---------------------|
| 67789 | 4151 | 6/4/2018 9:46:52 PM |
 ------------------------------------
```

I need to make a SQL query to extract the `ReceiptId` from `TABLE1`, and the count of records where (`TABLE1.JobId = TABLE2.JobId` & `TABLE1.SK = TABLE2.SK`) and `TABLE2.LogDate` is between `TABLE1.LogDate` and the next highest `TABLE1.LogDate`.

So the table result for this example would be:

```
           RESULT TABLE
 -----------------------------------------
| ReceiptId | JobId |  SK  | Clicks Count |
|-----------|-------|------|--------------|
| 0000001   | 67789 | 4151 |      3       |
|-----------|-------|------|--------------|
| 0000002   | 67789 | 4151 |      2       |
|-----------|-------|------|--------------|
| 0000003   | 67789 | 4151 |      1       |
 -----------------------------------------
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should specify the RDBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to left join `clicks` to `sends` then filter on the `logdate` and use `GROUP BY` and `count()`.

But your description and your desired sample output are inconsistent with one another.

So the following gets what your description is telling:

```
SELECT s.receiptid,
       s.jobid,
       s.sk,
       count(*)
       FROM sends s
            LEFT JOIN clicks c
                      ON c.jobid = s.jobid
                         AND c.sk = s.sk
       WHERE c.logdate >= s.logdate
             AND c.logdate <= (SELECT min(ss.logdate)
                                      FROM sends ss
                                      WHERE ss.logdate > s.logdate
                                            AND ss.jobid = s.jobid
                                            AND ss.sk = s.sk)
       GROUP BY s.receiptid,
                s.jobid,
                s.sk;
```

And the following gets your desired sample output:

```
SELECT s.receiptid,
       s.jobid,
       s.sk,
       count(*)
       FROM sends s
            LEFT JOIN clicks c
                      ON c.jobid = s.jobid
                         AND c.sk = s.sk
       WHERE c.logdate >= s.logdate
             AND c.logdate <= coalesce((SELECT min(ss.logdate)
                                               FROM sends ss
                                               WHERE ss.logdate > s.logdate
                                                     AND ss.jobid = s.jobid
                                                     AND ss.sk = s.sk),
                                       c.logdate)
       GROUP BY s.receiptid,
                s.jobid,
                s.sk;
```

Comment: Does this query count that 9:46 PM click ?  (Haven't tried, but it looks like it might not)

Comment: @ErwinSmout: No it didn't. But good point, the description and the desired sample output don't properly correspond. So I included the other case as well.

Comment: @stickybit could you maybe help me with this other sql query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756599/  Thank you in advance.